# tr command - how to replace the string "\n" with an actual newline (\n)

Tags: bash, tr

I would like to use the `tr` command to replace all occurrences of the string "`\n`" with a new line (`\n`).

I tried `tr '\\n' '\n'` but this just seems to match any '`\`' and any '`n`'

Comment: As @Aniket points out, `tr` won't work for this - it replaces a single byte with a single byte and can't deal with multi-byte strings ("\n"). You'll need `sed`, `awk` or another tool to accomplish this.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Here's how to do it with `sed`:

```
sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

Example usage:

To replace all occurrences of `\n` in a file in-place:

```
sed -i 's/\\n/\n/g' input_filename
```

To replace all occurrences of `\n` through a pipe, and save into another file

```
cat file1 file2 file3 file4 | sed 's/\\n/\n/g' > output_file
```

Comment: This does not work for me on bash 3 on OS X. It replaces \n with n.

Comment: @rjurney You need the GNU version of `sed` for this to work.  `brew install gnu-sed` then either use the `gsed` command or set your `$PATH` so that the GNU version takes precedence: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34815955/3316036

Comment: The Bash version makes no difference, but the `sed` version does. It is unfortunate that a nonportable version got accepted.

Comment: See the proposed duplicate for portability notes and a couple of portable alternatives.

Comment: I couldn't get this going with `gsed` on OSX; had to use the Perl solution in the answer below this one.

Answer (score 4):

The Perl solution is similar to the sed solution from *sampson-chen*:

```
perl -pe 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

**Examples:**

Input file with literal \n (not newlines):

```
$ cat test1.txt          
foo\nbar\n\nbaz
```

Replace all literal occurrences of `\n` with actual newlines, print into `STDOUT`:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\\n/\n/g' test1.txt
foo
bar

baz
```

Same, change the input file in-place, saving the backup into `test1.txt.bak`:

```
$ perl -i.bak -pe 's/\\n/\n/g' test1.txt
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue where I wanted to replace '\n' with new line on Mac BigSur

Input:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\\nMIGcz......\naLRn\\nyxiJdo=\\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Expected output:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIGcz......
aLRn
yxiJdo=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Sed, perl none worked for me. But a simple 'tr' command was useful.

```
echo -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\\nMIGcz......\\naLRn\\nyxiJdo=\\n-----END CERTIFICATE----- | tr '\' '\n'
```

Comment: This is broken, it replaces `\ ` with a newline and leaves the `n`.