# How to use GNU sed on Mac OS 10.10+, 'brew install --default-names' no longer supported

Tags: macos, bash, sed, homebrew, gnu

Under Mac OS 10.10.3, I installed gnu-sed by typing:

```
brew install gnu-sed --default-names
```

When I type it again, I get the message:

gnu-sed-4.2.2 already installed

However, even after rebooting the system and restarting Terminal, I still cannot use the GNU version of sed. For example:

```
echo a | sed ’s_A_X_i’
```

returns:
bad flag in substitution command 'i'

What should I do to get the GNU version working?
Here are the paths in my $PATH variable.

```
/Users/WN/-myUnix
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS
/opt/ImageMagick/bin
/usr/texbin
```

I'm sorry if my question seems obvious, but I am learning shell scripting on my own and don't quite understand yet how UNIX programs are installed. Any help to use GNU compliant commands (in this case sed, but soon I'll need others as well) on my Mac without causing damage or unnecessary clutter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where did `brew` install GNU `sed`?  Is that directory on your `PATH`?  What do you get if you type `sed --version`?  (BSD `sed` will complain; GNU `sed` will report its version information.)  Until you either have the `brew` directory on your PATH ahead of `/usr/bin` or you learn to use the absolute pathname to GNU `sed`, you will not be running GNU `sed`.  Be careful with quotes, too.  `’` is a word-processing quote, unlike `'`.

Answer (score 124):

Note (2019):

The `--with-default-names` option is [removed](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/search?q=default-names%20created%3A2019-01-01..2019-01-10&unscoped_q=default-names%20created%3A2019-01-01..2019-01-10&type=Commits) since January 2019, so now that option is not available anymore.

When installing, Homebrew instructs on how to adapt the path, if one wants to use sed without the `g` prefix.

---

You already have the gnu-sed installed without the `--with-default-names` option.

- With `--with-default-names` option it installs **`sed`** to `/usr/local/bin/`
- Without that option it installs **`gsed`**

So in your case what you gotta do is:

```
$ brew uninstall gnu-sed
$ brew install gnu-sed --with-default-names
```

Update path if needed...

```
$ echo $PATH | grep -q '/usr/local/bin'; [ $? -ne 0 ] && export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
$ echo a | sed 's_A_X_i'
```

or use **`gsed`** as others suggested.

Comment: --with-default-names option is no longer supported

Comment: Once --with-default-names is no longer supported, you can install it normally with `brew install gnu-sed` then get it's path with `brew info gnu-sed`.

Answer (score 67):

When you install the GNU version of `sed` for Mac OS X using:

```
$ brew install gnu-sed
```

The program that you use is **`gsed`**.

So for example:

```
$ echo "Calimero is a little chicken" > test
$ cat test
Calimero is a little chicken
$ gsed -i "s/little/big/g" test
$ cat test
Calimero is a big chicken
```

Also, to compliment the use of GNU command tools on Mac OS X, there is a nice blog post here to get the tools from linux:

[Install and use GNU command line tools on Mac OS/OS X](https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/)

Answer (score 27):

`$ brew install gnu-sed`

```
$ export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

With these two commands gnu-sed works properly

Comment: remember this only works for the current terminal session

Answer (score 21):

The `sed` that ships with OS X is in `/usr/bin`.

The `sed` that `homebrew` installs is in `/usr/local/bin`.

If you prefer to use the `homebrew` one, you have two options:

**Option 1**

Every time you want to use `homebrew` `sed`, type

```
/usr/local/bin/sed
```

or, preferably

**Option 2**

Move `/usr/local/bin/` ahead (i.e. before) `/usr/bin` in your PATH in your login profile, like this

```
 export PATH=/usr/local/bin:<other places>
```

Answer (score 9):

If you need to use gnu-sed command with their normal names, you
can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from your bashrc. Just use the following command in your bash or terminal.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 2):

`--with-default-names` didn't work for me on Mac OS X 10.14.2 so I created a symlink named `sed` to `gsed` higher in the `$PATH`

I also created a symlink named `sed.1` to the `gsed.1` manpage higher in the `$MANPATH` so `man` would access the `gsed` manpage instead of the default `sed` manpage

Comment: You can also do alias, e.g. `alias sed=gsed`.

Answer (score 1):

this export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"

is only valid per terminal SESSIOn as soon as you restart its GONE ( Mojave )

Comment: If you add it to `.bashrc` (if you use bash as your shell) or `.zshrc` if you're using zsh as your shell, it will be executed every time you log in.  Apple used to default to `bash` as the shell, but in Catalina switched the default shell to `zsh`.  You can tell which your account is set to use by running `w` in the terminal window - you'll get a bunch of lines, some of which (in my case, I use zsh) look like `jpb      s000     -                Sun20   1day  -zsh` - the `-zsh` shows my account is using `zsh`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that this is not a forum and answers like this will typically be downvoted. (If you ever get a downvoted answer, you can just remove it; that's all that's required to restore your points.) Instead we are typically looking for answers that include a direct solution to the OP's problem, and what you did to get there. For more information, see [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since the `--with-default-names` option was removed in Jan. 2019, my hack solution is:

```
# hack to override mac tools with homebrew versions (ls, sed, etc)
for p in `find "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}" -type d -name gnubin` ; do
    export PATH="${p}:${PATH}"
done
```

which is a little slow (crawling the dir every login) but works  without forcing me to modify my `.bashrc` for every gnu tool I happen to install with brew.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly faster way to do what @pjz suggests is the following:

```
for p in $(ls -d ${HOMEBREW_PREFIX:-/usr/local}/Cellar/*/*/libexec/gnubin); do
    export PATH="${p}:${PATH}"
done
```

Of course this assumes every GNU package in `brew` will always have the same level of directories to get to `gnubin`.

Alternatively, you can speed up `find` by adding the `-maxdepth 4` flag before `-type d` to reduce how far it has to do into directories.

Answer (score 0):

When running `brew install gnu-sed` on latest homebrew it reports at the end:

```
==> Caveats
GNU "sed" has been installed as "gsed".
If you need to use it as "sed", you can add a "gnubin" directory
to your PATH from your bashrc like:

    PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

`gnu-sed` installs by default as `gsed`. However, if you look in `/opt/homebrew/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubi` you'll find a `sed` command. So following the above instructions to update the path should mean `sed` runs `gnu-sed`.

Answer (score 0):

Once `--with-default-names` is no longer supported, you can install it normally with `brew install gnu-sed` and then get its path with `brew info gnu-sed`.

```
brew install gnu-sed
brew info gnu-sed
```

output:

```
...
==> Caveats
GNU "sed" has been installed as "gsed".
If you need to use it as "sed", you can add a "gnubin" directory
to your PATH from your bashrc like:

    PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
==> Analytics

...
```

Then use it in your path:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```