# Can I use grep and regex to find certain content from an file and write the content into a new file?

Tags: html, grep, xargs

I want to grep some content from an html by using regex and write that content into a new html. The example HTML is as below:

```
<html>
<script src='.....'>
</script>
<style>
...
</style>
<div class='header-outer'>
<div class='header-title'>
<div class='post-content'>
<noscript>
<p>content we want</p>
</noscript>
</div>
</div></div>
<div class='footer'>
</div>
</html>
```

Can I use grep to select content between `<div class='post-content'>`and`</div>` and write the content into a new html? So the new html would look like this:

```
<div class='post-content'>
<noscript>
<p>content we want</p>
</noscript>
</div>
```

I did some research on Stack overflow and found some code that might be helpful to my issue, like

`grep -L -Z -r "<div class='post-content'>.*?<\/noscript><\/dive>" .| xargs -0 -I{} mv {} DIR`?

Is it correct? If it is, what does `xargs` part mean? Thank you and I'm looking forward to your reply!

Comment: With GNU grep: `grep -Poz "(?s)<div class='post-content'>.*</div>" file.xml > new.html`

Comment: Hi Cyrus, I tried yours, but somehow it didn't work for me. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this GNU sed

```
sed -n "/<div class='post-content'>/,/<\/div>/p" file.html > output.html
```

-n is not printing
p is print those lines in range

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly! Now I'm thinking about how to adapt this piece of code to run through a folder that has, for example, 10 html files to extract the needed content and to generate new htmls...What other codes that I could add to this? Thanks! :)

Comment: Easy way will be using wildchars for input files like for example instead file.html using *.html and for output appending them in one file. For creating separate output files you will need some more complex bash script or using python ruby or similar languages

Comment: if you decide appending in one output file, command  could be sed -n "/<div class='post-content'>/,/<\/div>/p" *.html >> output.html

Comment: or this will be easiest idea: create backup folder of files, then use inplace editing with -i, so all files will be created with oneliner where names will be preserved sed -i -n "/<div class='post-content'>/,/<\/div>/p" *.html after backup of folder is created!

Comment: Hi Josifoski, thanks for your great answers! I found that by using your code, the original file gets amended too. So is it possible to just make changes to all the original htmls without writing to a new one...In that way I don't need to worry about the multiple output.htmls...I tried `sed -n "/<div class='post-content'>/,/<\/div>/p" file.html` it doesn't seem to work...Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. That is easiest idea which i've meant. Backup first then add -i in sed command like sed -i -n "/<div class='post-content'>/,/<\/div>/p" *.html

Comment: Well Penny it seems you've omitted *.html

Comment: Hey Josifoski, I tried the code `sed -i -n "/<div class='post-content'>/,/<\/div>/p" *.html`, but it looks like it doesn't change the original html as expected. Instead, a new html-n file were created, which looks the same as the original html without changes...Do you know why?

Comment: That command will not create new htmls but will edit inplace original ones. Probably you have ticked option show hidden files. Also best perfomance with sed is using gnu version. You can see it with sed --version

Comment: I'm not informed how nongnu seds will work in this case, maybe you are using some other sed. You are on linux, mac or ?

Comment: :) That was problem. Best recommendation is installing GNU sed, second choise you can drop eye here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux

Comment: Try sed -i.bak -n "/<div class='post-content'>/,/<\/div>/p" *.html without installing gnu sed, i'm not sure will work for many files, but maybe

Comment: Hi Josifoski, yep it doesn't seem to work. Thanks for your answer. I'm wondering if I could install GNU sed on my osx?

Comment: Yes! i think easiest way will be: brew install gnu-sed --with-default-names "as stated here" http://stackoverflow.com/a/27834828/2397101

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for keeping bothering you...I installed the gnu version, but I seem to continue using the old version. I tried to check the version of my sed (sed --version), but the terminal keeps telling me that I used illegal --. I also tried other ways to check the version, but in vain...

Comment: :) no problem. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003570/how-to-use-gnu-sed-on-mac-os-x

Comment: use gsed instead of sed now

Comment: Thank you! I moved the /usr/local/bin path ahead, so now it works! Hope this is my last question: can I write regex with the sed command like `sed -i -n "/<div class='post-content'>/,/<\/noscript><\/div>/p" *.html` or `sed -i -n "/<div class='post-content'>/,/<\/noscript.*?\/div>/p" *.html`? It seems like not working for me haha

Comment: no need for adding previous </noscript> line to be sure that correct </div> will be found, since sed will make range till first </div>. sed is working 'by lines', in case you still want complications, command can be modified and that included, but why?

Comment: Because in my case, I don't want the sed to stop searching at the first </div>, I need it to stop at the </div> after the </noscript> tag. The example I wrote in this post is just a sample. The real file that I'm dealing with is more complicated :)

Comment: sed is not correct tool for that requirement, -> python or similar

Comment: I'll do more research about it. But for now, I'll mark down the one that you wrote. It is very helpful thanks Josifoski!

Comment: wait, we can do something... give me 2-3min :)

Comment: difficult with sed, there is another tool called awk, i think that if you repost this question with additional requirements for bunch of files, for right interval with 2 lines tag it with awk in less then 10min you will receive complete answer

Comment: Thank you! Will try it out!

Comment: here: sed -i -e ':a; N; $! ba' -e "s/^.*\\(<div class='post-content'>.*<\/noscript> *\n *<\/div>\\).*$/\1/g" *.html

Comment: note that </noscript> and </div> must be in separate lines, \n is for newline

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works great! Although I can't understand what's in there. but it works great!! Is it possible to explain it a little bit about what it means?

Comment: Glad to help. ':a; N; $! ba' reads whole file in pattern space for \n to may be catched. In other words we treat file as one string. (default's sed behaviour is treat string per line.) <\/noscript>space*\nspace* is (space* to catch eventual not polished ie trimmed interested lines, so space* is catching zero or more spaces) \1 is replacement part for everything which is between \\(  \\). If you like better sed understanding http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sed/index.htm