# Insert string at certain line of code in header file from bash script

Tags: objective-c, bash, sed

I'm trying to insert encoded, encrypted content at certain line of code in `header file (.h)` in `Xcode` project which is written in `Objective-C`, from bash script. Also, I work in `mac (OS X)`.
Code in script that I have now is this:

```
sed -n '' "10i
$jsonConfigFileContent
" Sources/ConfigurationInteractor.h
```

And when I execute the script from terminal I get next error:

```
sed: 10i
#define jsonConfigFileContent @"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"
```

**Error:** File name too long

If the `jsonConfigFileContent` is smaller (has less characters) the insertion works fine. But when this string is big I get this error. How to insert large string at certain line of code in header (h.) file and how to fix this error? Thanks for your answers.

**EDIT:**
Another code that I was using in this script is this:

```
sed -i -e "10i\ 
$(echo $jsonConfigFileContent)
" Sources/VWConfigurationInteractor.h
```

but I would get this error:

```
sed: 3: "10i\ 
#define jsonConfi ...": invalid command code T
```

Also works fine with smaller strings, but when string is large it doesn't work. Besides `invalid command code T` I get the same error but with different letters.

Comment: what does the single quotes do in your command or perhaps a typo?.. can you also show the smaller string which worked? the error doesn't seem to suggest lengthy string to be an issue.. could be just some special characters in your variable wrecking havoc

Comment: you can also try if this works: `(head -n9 file ; echo "$var" ; sed '1,9d' file) > outfile`

Comment: The `''` suffix  if for use with `-i` option. eg `sed -i''`. Try to remove it.

Comment: @Sundeep - Single quotes are there because of some other suggestion. Any other smaller string would succeed. A string with few lines. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Kenavoz - I've tried to remove `''` and it wont work.

Comment: And you should escape the double quotes in the variable value. You can do it with Bash parameter expansion : `${jsonConfigFileContent//\"/\\\"}`

Comment: For large string, you'd better use /r comand of sed  to insert file to certain position, see [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-37) for examples.

Comment: @Sundeep, Kenavoz - I've edited my question.

Comment: @Kenavoz - when use `${jsonConfigFileContent//\"/\\\"}` I get this error: 
`sed: 3: "10i\ 
#define jsonConfi ...": extra characters at the end of l command`

Comment: @gzh - Thanks for link, I'll check it out.

Comment: I tried `seq 12 | sed "10i$a"` and it works just fine.. `$a` contains the huge string from your first error log.. but tested on GNU sed 4.2.2, so not sure if  sed on your OSX differs in subtle ways...

Comment: @Sundeep - No, it wont work. I got this error:

`invalid command code B`

Comment: this doesn't work too? `(head -n9 file ; echo "$var" ; sed '1,9d' file) > outfile` and let us know if `r` command reading from file works out.. that should be more reliable..

Comment: @Sundeep - this works, but it replaces all content from file with this string. It should be inserted at line 10 in that same file. Rest of the content in that file should be the same, intact.

Comment: it does insert at line 10 and leaves everything else same.. that is the intention with stringing together 3 different commands.. I have no idea why any of our suggestion continues to fail.. and I cannot reproduce the error you get because am not on OSX.. hope someone else will be able to help you...

Comment: one last suggestion: install GNU sed on OSX: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003570/how-to-use-gnu-sed-on-mac-os-x

Comment: @Sundeep - thanks a lot for your help, I appreciate it. This is a progress also, at least it finally inserted LARGE string in the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you could use awk.

Set the value in a variable (with single quotes):

```
a='#define jsonConfigFileContent @"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"'
```

And then execute:

```
$ awk -v a="$a" 'NR==3{printf("%s\n",a)};1' Sources/ConfigurationInteractor.h
```

Comment: No luck. Doesn't work. `: extra characters at the end of g command`

Comment: @MattCodes Changed to awk (if you can use it).

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this issue. In the header file I had to add pattern variables to the certain line of code. And than in bash script I added:

```
sed -i "" "s|#define jsonConfigFileContent.*|$(echo $define$jsonConfigFileContent$lastMark)|g" Sources/ConfigurationInteractor.h
```

And it finally worked.