# How do I fix "sed: illegal option -- r" in macOS Sierra Android build?

Tags: android, macos, sed, build, compilation

I am trying to build Android on my MacOS, but it gives me this error:

> "sed: illegal option -- r"

I tried:

```
make bootimage
make systemimage
make recovery
brunch
mka bacon
```

All of them give me the same error.

Comment: If you talk about the classic stream editor `sed` and option `-r` that enables extended regex, then this can be done in MAC with `sed -E`. Is this you talk about or i lost you?

Comment: yes, thats exactly what i meant. but i need to change it in the makefiles of the rom i am compiling. and i cant find wehre the sed -r is used. thank you for your answer.

Comment: Welcome. You can just substitute all instances referring to `sed -r` with  `sed -E` since it is the same thing. sed -E will work on mac and all other distros with no problem.

Comment: thank you!! but do you know which makefile in the build directory of an android source the sed -r is used? because i cant find it.

Comment: Did you try something like `grep -r 'sed -r' /android/dir/*` ? This will scan all the files in a directory for sed -r. Or you can just `grep 'sed -r' file` to search in a particular file

Comment: no, i did not ry that. did not know how to do. thank you.

Answer (score 34):

Another option is to use homebrew to install gnu-sed:

```
brew install gnu-sed --with-default-names
```

Comment: And use `gsed` instead of `sed` - at least in my case on High Sierra

Comment: If you want to use `sed` instead of `gsed` the `--with-default-names` option does not work any more. Instead you have to add gnu-sed to the path: `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"`

Comment: Error: invalid option: --with-default-names

Comment: `--with-default-names` option [has been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34815955/337194).

Comment: `ln -s /usr/local/bin/gsed /usr/local/bin/sed`

Answer (score 5):

Editing PATH manually is one way to handle this.
However, there is an alternative solution that might work for some.

Most developers these days have [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).
conda can install the latest `sed` and make it visible via $PATH

`conda install -c conda-forge sed`

conda takes care of editing PATH variable

P.S.
Most believe that conda is a package manager for python, but that is not entirely true! I install everything using conda. And it manages environment variables such as `PATH` really well.
https://superuser.com/a/1304148/266871

Comment: This is an interesting way to handle it. However, I would say it's quite a stretch to claim that "most developers these days have `conda`". Can you back up that claim? Even most of the Python devs I work with don't have `conda`...