# FAILED sepolicy check - Android 10 building - Pixel 3a XL

Tags: android, android-source

I am Using MacOS Catalina to build Android OS for Pixel 3a XL device. I am hitting a dead-end with the following "sepolicy" errors with segmentation fault.

[  0% 23/22799] build out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_28.0_intermediates/treble_sepolicy_tests_28.0
FAILED: out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_28.0_intermediates/treble_sepolicy_tests_28.0
/bin/bash -c "(out/host/darwin-x86/bin/treble_sepolicy_tests -l         out/host/darwin-x86/lib64/libsepolwrap.dylib  -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/plat_file_contexts_intermediates/plat_file_contexts  -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/vendor_file_contexts_intermediates/vendor_file_contexts  -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/product_file_contexts_intermediates/product_file_contexts        -b out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/built_plat_sepolicy_intermediates/built_plat_sepolicy -m out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_28.0_intermediates/28.0_mapping.combined.cil      -o out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_28.0_intermediates/built_28.0_plat_sepolicy -p out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy         -u out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/built_plat_sepolicy_intermediates/base_plat_pub_policy.cil ) && (touch out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_28.0_intermediates/treble_sepolicy_tests_28.0 )"
/bin/bash: line 1: 13824 Segmentation fault: 11  ( out/host/darwin-x86/bin/treble_sepolicy_tests -l out/host/darwin-x86/lib64/libsepolwrap.dylib -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/plat_file_contexts_intermediates/plat_file_contexts -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/vendor_file_contexts_intermediates/vendor_file_contexts -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/product_file_contexts_intermediates/product_file_contexts -b out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/built_plat_sepolicy_intermediates/built_plat_sepolicy -m out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_28.0_intermediates/28.0_mapping.combined.cil -o out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_28.0_intermediates/built_28.0_plat_sepolicy -p out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy -u out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/built_plat_sepolicy_intermediates/base_plat_pub_policy.cil )
[  0% 28/22799] build out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/sepolicy_tests_intermediates/sepolicy_tests
FAILED: out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/sepolicy_tests_intermediates/sepolicy_tests
/bin/bash -c "(out/host/darwin-x86/bin/sepolicy_tests -l out/host/darwin-x86/lib64/libsepolwrap.dylib        -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/plat_file_contexts_intermediates/plat_file_contexts  -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/vendor_file_contexts_intermediates/vendor_file_contexts  -p out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy ) && (touch out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/sepolicy_tests_intermediates/sepolicy_tests )"
/bin/bash: line 1: 13822 Segmentation fault: 11  ( out/host/darwin-x86/bin/sepolicy_tests -l out/host/darwin-x86/lib64/libsepolwrap.dylib -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/plat_file_contexts_intermediates/plat_file_contexts -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/vendor_file_contexts_intermediates/vendor_file_contexts -p out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy )
[  0% 29/22799] build out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_26.0_intermediates/treble_sepolicy_tests_26.0
FAILED: out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_26.0_intermediates/treble_sepolicy_tests_26.0
/bin/bash -c "(out/host/darwin-x86/bin/treble_sepolicy_tests -l         out/host/darwin-x86/lib64/libsepolwrap.dylib  -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/plat_file_contexts_intermediates/plat_file_contexts  -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/vendor_file_contexts_intermediates/vendor_file_contexts  -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/product_file_contexts_intermediates/product_file_contexts        -b out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/built_plat_sepolicy_intermediates/built_plat_sepolicy -m out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_26.0_intermediates/26.0_mapping.combined.cil      -o out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_26.0_intermediates/built_26.0_plat_sepolicy -p out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy         -u out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/built_plat_sepolicy_intermediates/base_plat_pub_policy.cil ) && (touch out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_26.0_intermediates/treble_sepolicy_tests_26.0 )"
/bin/bash: line 1: 13821 Segmentation fault: 11  ( out/host/darwin-x86/bin/treble_sepolicy_tests -l out/host/darwin-x86/lib64/libsepolwrap.dylib -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/plat_file_contexts_intermediates/plat_file_contexts -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/vendor_file_contexts_intermediates/vendor_file_contexts -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/product_file_contexts_intermediates/product_file_contexts -b out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/built_plat_sepolicy_intermediates/built_plat_sepolicy -m out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_26.0_intermediates/26.0_mapping.combined.cil -o out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_26.0_intermediates/built_26.0_plat_sepolicy -p out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy -u out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/built_plat_sepolicy_intermediates/base_plat_pub_policy.cil )
[  0% 30/22799] build out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_27.0_intermediates/treble_sepolicy_tests_27.0
FAILED: out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_27.0_intermediates/treble_sepolicy_tests_27.0
/bin/bash -c "(out/host/darwin-x86/bin/treble_sepolicy_tests -l         out/host/darwin-x86/lib64/libsepolwrap.dylib  -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/plat_file_contexts_intermediates/plat_file_contexts  -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/vendor_file_contexts_intermediates/vendor_file_contexts  -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/product_file_contexts_intermediates/product_file_contexts        -b out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/built_plat_sepolicy_intermediates/built_plat_sepolicy -m out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_27.0_intermediates/27.0_mapping.combined.cil      -o out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_27.0_intermediates/built_27.0_plat_sepolicy -p out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy         -u out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/built_plat_sepolicy_intermediates/base_plat_pub_policy.cil ) && (touch out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_27.0_intermediates/treble_sepolicy_tests_27.0 )"
/bin/bash: line 1: 13823 Segmentation fault: 11  ( out/host/darwin-x86/bin/treble_sepolicy_tests -l out/host/darwin-x86/lib64/libsepolwrap.dylib -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/plat_file_contexts_intermediates/plat_file_contexts -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/vendor_file_contexts_intermediates/vendor_file_contexts -f out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/product_file_contexts_intermediates/product_file_contexts -b out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/built_plat_sepolicy_intermediates/built_plat_sepolicy -m out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_27.0_intermediates/27.0_mapping.combined.cil -o out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_27.0_intermediates/built_27.0_plat_sepolicy -p out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy -u out/target/product/bonito/obj/ETC/built_plat_sepolicy_intermediates/base_plat_pub_policy.cil )
00:20:17 ninja failed with: exit status 1

failed to build some targets (25 seconds)

Comment: Using case-sensitive disk image?

Comment: yes I am using case-sensitive disk image.

Comment: It is about darwin-x86 compatibility with Catalina it seems ....

Comment: Any one know more about this issue ?  I am also running catalina ...

Comment: I'm also running Catalina, and have the same issue.
My build fails after 3 hours...

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
make SELINUX_IGNORE_NEVERALLOWS=true
```

Comment: It works on Catalina. Needs also the [gsed fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696304/how-do-i-fix-sed-illegal-option-r-in-macos-sierra-android-build).