# 'sed: illegal option -- r usage' error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just updated my Visual Studio application (now 1.71.0 (Universal)) on my Mac (High Sierra), and I noticed that when I start up my terminal in VSCode, that I get this message with every command that I run:

```
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
```

I think this has something to do with me updating VS Code, but I don't know why or how to fix it. Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 11):

## Straightforward solution

Please, see the following references:

- GitHub issue. [[MacOs][Bug][Terminal] `sed: illegal option -- r` before executing commands · Issue #159864 · microsoft/vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/159864).
- GitHub pull request. [[main] Remove reliance on sed -r by Tyriar · Pull Request #160209 · microsoft/vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/160209).
- GitHub pull request. [[release/1.71] Remove reliance on sed -r by Tyriar · Pull Request #160210 · microsoft/vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/160210).

The solution is:

1. To wait for a next Visual Studio Code release with the resolved issue.
2. To upgrade to the release.

As per the [GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/159864#issuecomment-1243699140):

> #### **[Tyriar](https://github.com/Tyriar)** commented [2022-09-12T12:54:25Z](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/159864#issuecomment-1243699140)
>
> The fix for this is coming in 1.71.2, not sure on the release date currently.

### Available release: `1.71.2`

- Release. [Release August 2022 Recovery 2 · microsoft/vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/releases/tag/1.71.2).
- Tag. [microsoft/vscode at 1.71.2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/1.71.2).

## Workaround solution #1

Please, see the GitHub issue: [sed -r shell integration error on OSX · Issue #159946 · microsoft/vscode · GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/159946).

Please, note the [workaround-related comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/159946#issue-1360542272):

> #### **[Tyriar](https://github.com/Tyriar)** commented [2022-09-02T19:31:19Z](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/159946#issue-1360542272)
>
> See comments in [e55863c](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/e55863c5c1fc4515bd99e9cd4fb415788000a8b1)
>
> > sed -r doesn't work on OSX Catalina, I get an error at each command in the integrated terminal
>
> Workaround for anyone hitting this is to set `HISTCONTROL` to one of `erasedups`, `ignoreboth`, `ignoredups` in your `~/.bashrc`.

## Workaround solution #2

The solution is to override («replace») the macOS (BSD) `sed` with the GNU `sed`.

For example, please, refer:

- Question. [How do I fix "sed: illegal option -- r" in macOS Sierra Android build? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696304/how-do-i-fix-sed-illegal-option-r-in-macos-sierra-android-build).

  - [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46859893).
- Question. [macos - How to use GNU sed on Mac OS 10.10+, 'brew install --default-names' no longer supported - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003570/how-to-use-gnu-sed-on-mac-os-10-10-brew-install-default-names-no-longer-su).

  - [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34815955).

Answer (score 4):

This may not be the most technically savvy solution, but I did this:

1. Install `gsed`:

   ```
   brew install gnu-sed
   ```
2. Make a symbolic link to `gsed`:

   ```
   cd /usr/local/bin
   ln -s gsed sed
   ```

When VSCode fixes the issue, I will delete the symbolic link, and uninstall `gsed`.

Answer (score 1):

Im using Catalina and solved this problem with downgrading to v1.70 universal
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70

First sync everything, change the update method to manual and simply delete the VSCode and install v1.70. Everything you added (extensions, icons etc) comes back immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If you're more generally trying to write a `sed` command and receiving this error on macOS, you can replace the `-r` flag with a  `-E` flag in your command (even though the manual does state that `-r` is a valid synonym).

Answer (score 0):

previously, I'm working with macOS Catalina 10.15.7 and VSCode 1.71. I got the same bug when I ran any commands on the latest version of VSCode.

as my temporary solution, I don't use the latest version and choose the older version of VSCode (now I'm using version 1.69.1. you can use version 1.70 or another version excluding 1.71). and it works on me :).

if you using macOS and want another solution, you can change the shell in your terminal from bash to zsh. it works on me too.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac OS X with MacPorts I solved it with a symbolic link to use GNU sed:

```
sudo port install gsed
cd /opt/local/bin
ln -s gsed sed
```

Answer (score 0):

change your terminal shell from bash to zsh
it worked for me!
steps:
go to settings >command palette > select default profile > select zsh