# How to toggle cases with sed command?

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I want to replace `kAbcdedf` with `abcdef` in a file. I try to use the sed command. Some suggestions said, if I input this command

```
echo 'abc'|sed 's/^../\u&/'
```

the result will be

```
Abc
```

but on macOS (using zsh), the result is

```
uabc
```

Does anyone know the correct way to toggle cases with the sed command?

How can I search `kAbcd` and then replace that string with `abcd`, i.e., remove `k` and uppercase the next letter after `k`?

Comment: can you please change the tag from linux to mac? as far as I know, the sed on mac(not sure what it is called exactly) doesn't support `\u`

Comment: You need GNU sed to use that feature. See [How to use GNU sed on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003570/how-to-use-gnu-sed-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: also, based on example given, you want to lowercase the character after `k`, not uppercase

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks a lot. let me have a try

Answer (score 2):

```
$ # with GNU sed
$ echo 'kAbcd' | sed -E 's/k(.)/\l\1/'
abcd

$ # with perl if GNU sed is not available
$ echo 'kAbcd' | perl -pe 's/k(.)/\l$1/'
abcd
```

- `\l` will lowercase the first character of given argument
- use `g` modifier to replace all such occurrences in a line

As mentioned by Wiktor Stribiżew in comments, see also: [How to use GNU sed on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003570/how-to-use-gnu-sed-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: By the way, if I  want with GNU sed to covert abcd.kAbcd to abcd.abcd, how should I write command? thanks~

Comment: the same command as mentioned in the answer.. by default, matching is done anywhere in the line.. you can change that using anchors, word boundaries and other things.. see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-regular-expressions for details