# Multiplying all values in a txt file with another value

Tags: bash, awk, sed, find

My aim is to multiply all values in a text file with a number. In my case it is 1000.

Original text in file:

```
0.00493293814
0.0438981727
0.149746656
0.443125129
0.882018387
0.975789607
0.995755374
1
```

I want the output to look like: 
(so, changing the contents of the file to...)

```
4.93293814
43.8981727
149.746656
443.125129
882.018387
975.789607
995.755374
1000
```

Or even rather:

```
4.9
43.8
149.7
443.1
882.0
975.7
995.7
1000
```

I am using bash on macOS in the terminal.

Comment: note that `975.78` is closer to `975.8`, you may want to round the numbers instead of truncating.

Comment: What DO you want done wrt rounding? rounded up or down or unbiased or truncated or something else or do you really not care?

Comment: Is `1000` fixed (make it a string operation moving the dot after adding some `0`) ?

Comment: If one of the answers here resolved your question please accept that answer. Accepting an answer closes this questions and rewards the author of the accepted answer. If your question was not resolved consider explaining why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sed` to prefix each line with `1000*`, then process the resulting mathematical expressions with `bc`. To show only the first digit after the decimal point you can use `sed` again.

```
sed 's/^/1000*/' yourFile | bc | sed -E 's/(.*\..).*/\1/'
```

This will print the latter of your expected outputs. Just as you wanted, decimals are cut rather than rounded (`1.36` is converted to `1.3`).

To remove all decimal digits either replace the last `… | sed …` with `sed -E 's/\..*//'` or use the following command

```
sed 's:^.*$:1000*&/1:' yourFile | bc
```

With these commands overwriting the file directly is not possible. You have to write to a temporary file (append `> tmp && mv tmp yourFile`) or use the `sponge` command from the package `moreutils` (append `| sponge yourFile`).

However, if you want to remove all decimal points after the multiplication there is a trick. Instead of actually multiplying by 1000 we can syntactically shift the decimal point. This can be done in one single `sed` command. `sed` has the `-i` option to overwrite input files.

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/\..*/&000/;s/^[^.]*$/&.000/;s/\.(...).*/\1/;s/^(-?)0*(.)/\1\2/' yourFile
```

The command changes `yourFile`'s content to

```
4
43
149
443
882
975
995
1000
```

A backup `yourFile.bak` of the original is created.

The single `sed` command should work with every input number format too (even for things like `-.1` → `-100`).

Comment: Used `sed` before and this one is working, except for it not destructively writing over the file. While I´d want that for some files, the current need is only to wrangle the numbers. This one did that perfectly. Is there a way to get rid of all of the decimals and the "." (dot) as well?

Comment: Re *"overwrite ... not possible"*: with *GNU* `sed`'s **`e`**_valuate_ command it can be done like `sed -i 's/.*/'"dc -e '1000 & * p'"'/e'  yourFile`.  It's more inefficient, (using a separate instance of `dc` for each line), but doesn't require `sponge`.

Comment: @agc good to know. However OP is using mac os which does not come with GNU sed.

Comment: @Socowi, True, but `gsed` can be had should that seem necessary.  See [How to use GNU sed on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003570/how-to-use-gnu-sed-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 2):

If you have dc :

```
cat infile | dc -f - -e '1k1000sa[la*Sdz0!=Z]sZzsclZx[Ld1/psblcd1-sc1<Y]sYlYx'
```

Comment: Have my vote for maddest answer I've seen in 5 years on Stack Overflow!

Comment: in this particular case can't beat doing the computation by hand though!

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl

```
perl -lpe ' $_=$_*1000 '
```

with inputs and inline replacing

```
$ cat andy.txt
0.00493293814
0.0438981727
0.149746656
0.443125129
0.882018387
0.975789607
0.995755374
1

$ perl -i -lpe ' $_=$_*1000 ' andy.txt

$ cat andy.txt
4.93293814
43.8981727
149.746656
443.125129
882.018387
975.789607
995.755374
1000

$
```

One decimal place

```
perl -lpe ' $_=sprintf("%0.1f",$_*1000 ) '
```

Zero decimal place and rounding off

```
perl -lpe ' $_=sprintf("%0.0f",$_*1000 ) '
```

Zero decimal place and Truncating

```
perl  -lpe ' $_=sprintf("%0.0f",int($_*1000) ) '
```

Comment: Perfect and concise. Works well. How would I go about having one decimal or none at all?

Comment: for one  decimal ````perl  -lpe ' $_=sprintf("%0.1f",$_*1000 ) '````

Comment: for no decimal ````perl  -lpe ' $_=sprintf("%0.0f",$_*1000 ) ' andy.txt````.. note that it rounds off

Comment: ````perl  -lpe ' $_=sprintf("%0.0f",int($_*1000) ) '```` for truncating.. added all of them to the answer

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{printf "%.1f\n", $1*1000}' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [num-utils](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/).  For answers to 8 decimal places:

```
numprocess '/*1000/' n.txt
```

For rounded answers to 1 decimal place:

```
numprocess '/*1000/' n.txt | numround -n '.1'
```