# Is there a relative case specifier for gsed?

Tags: macos, sed, homebrew, gnu

The case insensitive substitution signifier in a sed command appears itself to be case insensitive. Appending i/I to the sed statement seems to give the same result.

```
echo a | gsed ’s_A_Z_i’
```

returns: Z

```
echo a | gsed ’s_A_Z_I’
```

also returns: Z

```
echo A | gsed ’s_A_z_I’
```

returns: z

```
echo A | gsed ’s_a_Z_i’
```

returns: Z

gsed returns the case-specific substitute text.

Is there a compact way to specify a case insensitive search with replacement in the case matching that of the find?
(replace a with z and A with Z)

Of course, the problem could be solved with two commands but I'm looking for something more compact.

Secondarily, is there a difference in the effect of the i/I suffix? (Not the -i flag)

This follows from, but differs from [a previous question]([How to use GNU sed on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003570/how-to-use-gnu-sed-on-mac-os-x/33756193?newreg=081a89b6f346430f98d76d20ae701bda))! on the use of gnu-sed in OSX, after standard homebrew installation.

I do not have a specific application in mind. I'm learning some of the intricacies of gnu-sed on OSX and would like to know how it handles case.

Comment: Are you wanting to flip the case of characters? Make all lower case ones upper and visa versa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `i/I` option to the `s` command modifies only the `PATTERN` and does not
affect the `REPLACEMENT`. Please imagine the following usage:

```
str='Login'
echo "$str" | sed 's/login/Login/i'
```

This example attempts to *normalize* the input into the `upper camel case`
to accept both `login` and `Login`. If the `i/I` option affects the
`REPLACEMENT`, we cannot obtain the expected result.

If you want to map a to z and A to Z, try instead:

```
sed y/Aa/Zz/
```